# SuperWebSocket server can receive only one message

Tags: c#, websocket

I followed an [example](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/discussions/353151) at SuperWebSocket discussions to create a tiny web socket server with echo functionality. However, my server can receive and send back only one message, when I try to send second message to it, the connection closes. I use [this echo page](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) to test my server.

Here is my code (I use WPF without MVVM here):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WebSocketServer ws;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var r = new RootConfig();

        var s = new ServerConfig();
        s.Name = "SuperWebSocket";
        s.Ip = "Any";
        s.Port = 8089;
        s.Mode = SocketMode.Tcp;

        var f = new SocketServerFactory();

        if (ws != null)
        {
            ws.Stop();
            ws = null;
        }

        ws = new WebSocketServer();
        ws.Setup(r, s, f);
        ws.NewMessageReceived += ws_NewMessageReceived;
        ws.Start();
    }

    private void ws_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string e)
    {
        session.Send("Message: " + e);
    }
}
```

I can send messages from the server without problems, but can't receive more than one message without closing the connection. What is the reason of this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you see in the Google Chrome console what is the error is showing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DepartamentoB sorry, I can still remember what that task was about, but I don't really remember anything about this exact problem. My bad that I forgot about this question back then.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
ws.NewMessageReceived += ws_NewMessageReceived;
```

with:

```
ws.NewMessageReceived += new SuperWebSocket.SessionEventHandler<SuperWebSocket.WebSocketSession, string>(ws_NewMessageReceived);
```